# Create weekly folders, then move contents of folders with same month in filename

Tags: applescript, directory, organization, automator

I've got a question that I think would be of general interest to people who like to store things in weekly folders within monthly folders but don't want the hassle of creating them manually.

I am currently using Automator to create folders to store files I've downloaded & keep them in weekly folders. At the moment, every time I save a batch of files I move them into  my Downloads folder with the filename format '5 November New Music'. I then have a separate action which moves them into a folder called 'November 2014 New Music'. The next day if I save a batch of files it will be saved into '6 November New Music' and moved into 'November 2014 New Music'.

The folders look something like this:

November 2014 New Music

...1 November New Music

...8 November New Music

...12 November New Music

and so on

But what I really want is weekly folders, so I have also written an action which finds all the folders with the numbers 1 through 7 and then moves their contents into a newly created '1-7 November 2014 New Music' folder.

I'm getting to the question, I promise!

Now, this has taken an awful lot of probably error-prone Automator action work. Is there not a simpler and less risky way I can turn the filename into a variable to move, on a monthly basis, the folders

1 November New Music

6 November New Music

7 November New Music

into a folder called '1-7 November 2014 New Music', and folders called

8 November New Music

9 November New Music

14 November New Music

into a folder called '8-14 November 2014 New Music', and so on?

Maybe it'd be more simply put in a diagrammatic form. I want to click on my 'Downloads' folder, and find the following structure:

January 2014 New Music

...1-7 January New Music

(containing all the files/folders in the folders '1 January New Music', '3 January New Music', '6 January New Music' and '7 January New Music')

...8-14 January New Music

...15-22 January New Music

...22-end January New Music

February 2014 New Music

and so on...

What I can't seem to do is make a workflow that can identify all the folders within a certain folder that begin with a number between 1 and 7 and where the next word in the filename being 'January' and then get it to move their contents to a folder called '1-7 January'. Automator is too blunt a tool to accomplish this, it seems, and my Applescript is really quite basic, but it seems like the sort of thing that would work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Tardy

Comment: This is absolutely something you could do with Applescript. What would be helpful, at least for me, is if you showed exactly the file path of the source files (including file name) and the destination path you'd like them to land in. For example:  **Source path** = Macintosh HD:Users:UserName:Downloads:SomeFolder:FileA.mp3    **Destination Path** = Macintosh HD:Users:UserName:Downloads:1-7 January:FileA.mp3  It would be helpful to better understand how you are determining what is the "Month" and the "Day" for each file. Based on the download date? or the sub-folder you've already placed it in?

Comment: Thanks ThrowBack, hasn't seen this because didn't get an email notification... 

So the source path= Macintosh HD:Temp to be Listened to:Temp:1 November New Music
and the destination = Macintosh HD:Temp to be Listened to:Temp:November 2014 New Music
I save files in batches which are sent in folders named by the date I hit the action - so if I save them on the 1st Nov, they are moved into a folder in Temp called '1 November New Music'.
Thanks for your help!
Tardy